# php replace string and read full string

Tags: php

i am trying to achieve this. I have alot of HTMLs that looks somethinglike this (for example).

```
<div>
    <img src="http://firstsite.com/path/to/img/main.jpg" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;" />
</div>
```

Now i try to make a php that automatically changes the path of the images to another website, but i also want to download the images and put them into same folder structure. So far i did this:

```
    $input = "c:/wamp/www/primo/input12";
    $output = "c:/wamp/www/primo/output12";


    $handle  = opendir($input);
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {

            $data = file_get_contents($input . "/" . $file);

            $data = str_replace("http://firstsite.com/", "http://secondsite.com", $data);

            file_put_contents($output . "/" . $file, $data);

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

This changes the path but now i need to somehow get into a variable the full path `http://firstsite.com/path/to/img/main.jpg` in my example in order to download the image.

Is there a way to get the full path of the images while replacing `http://firstsite.com/` which is just the begining of the path ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: Most probably. With the help of a regular expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get only images:

```
$data = file_get_contents($input . "/" . $file);

preg_match_all('/\<img.*src=\"(.+?)\"/s', $data, $matches);
//go through the match array and download your files

$data = str_replace("http://firstsite.com/", "http://secondsite.com", $data);
file_put_contents($output . "/" . $file, $data);
```

Get all pathes:

```
$data = file_get_contents($input . "/" . $file);

preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/firstsite\.com([^\s]+?)/s', $data, $matches);
//go through the match array and download your files

$data = str_replace("http://firstsite.com/", "http://secondsite.com", $data);
file_put_contents($output . "/" . $file, $data);
```

Comment: it seems you understood correctly my issue, but the problem is not all the html elements are imgs, there are different paths with different files and i must search them just by the http://firstsite.com/ which is the begining of the path

Comment: thank you very much Manu, i've made my php work with your code to get all paths and burgeris regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/firstsite\.com\/[^\s]*)/', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: Will fail in delimiter

Comment: I mean non-escaped delimiters (which you've replaced after your edit)

Comment: Thank you, i have combined Manu's answer with your regular expression to make everything work :)